# Nuget error install package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I have a problem with the update Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. 

There was version 5.0.0, when you start the development environment, the management offered me a package to update components. All components are successfully updated, except that package. 
I just receive the message: `"Failed to recovery package. Package rollback changes to ***."` 
What to do with this problem, I do not know. Inet clambered, tried to remove the package and put again (by removing the package is not compromised with the same error).

Comment: I can quickly upgrade to version 5.1.0. Note also that the installation of some packages through nuget stop with the same error.

Comment: If you reset your VS settings, and then re-create a new project, how about the result? Please also check this connect report here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1617801/newly-created-universal-app-projects-dont-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error like the following screen shot, two suggestions:

[image]

(1)Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General, please checked "Save new projects when created" option.

(2)Install the latest packages:

Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/5.2.2