# Cannot install Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-10-universal, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-iot-core

Seemed to be related to this:
[Nuget error install package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749164/nuget-error-install-package-microsoft-netcore-universalwindowsplatform)
but it is not, because the checkbox is checked by default in vs2017. I am running the creators update by the way and everything is up-to-date.

I have just started a new C# background IoT project and got this:

[image]

When manually installing the package in the package console I got this:

> ...
>
> Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler 1.6.0' to projectnamehere
>
> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit.1.0.3' does not exist in project
>
> ...
>
> Package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit.1.0.3' does not exist in folder
>
> ...
>
> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.0.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that f
>   ramework. For more information, contact the package author.

seems related to this https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1617801/newly-created-universal-app-projects-dont-work

but I have no idea how to fix it.
I have also seen a website suggesting to remove the project.json file, which I did but did not resolve it.

I have also closed vs2017 and modified the installtion to verify that the creators update sdk was checked and installed.

I have lowered the target version in the project props, but that did not help either.

[image]

*edit* manual install the jit package did not work either:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.NETCore.Jit 1.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

**edit2** funny thing is that the solution explorer tells me that there is a project.json while there is none in windows explorer:

[image]

I verified the sdk installation by hitting the modify button of the vs2017 installation and tried to create a new project afterwards but got the exact same issue again.

Comment: Same, new Windows Console App, then install-package microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform fails with Could not install package Microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform.

Comment: @wind-rider's workaround works. You can have a try.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT can you explain why the workaround works? And if there will be an update soon to fix this?

Comment: This is Visual Studio/VS template issue, reported. The related team is investigating it. And Please have a try on VS2017 Update1. Use @wind-rider's solution temporarily if this issue still exists

Comment: I have not yet heard of an update 1 for vs2017. I did find an update 1 rc2 but that is for TFS and not VS. Is it public? and thanks btw for the reply Rita! :)

Comment: VS2017 Update 1 (build 26403.3) released on April 5th; still exhibits this issue.  Unable to create new IoT background projects from template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: Microsoft updated the templates in their github (https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/commit/2e2aa34ab514b8c0725a53263898a412e0a1be1c) but didn't push it as an updated templates package to Visual Studio yet. Changed the answer accordingly.

Temporary fix:

- replace in your .csproj file

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- A reference to the entire .Net Framework and Windows SDK are automatically included -->
  <None Include="project.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

with

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

- add the Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform package

Optional extra:
Add the Windows IoT Extension SDK via the references dialog

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed for Visual Studio 2017 in updated templates released here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MicrosoftIoT.WindowsIoTCoreProjectTemplatesforVS15

Comment: 21st of April, it was not fixed at the time that @wind-rider gave the workaround. Though thanks for the update that this is resolved now.

Comment: I still get the same error even though I have that version (21 april) of the templates in VS2017...