# Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64'

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I want to update [Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/) but it shows an error

`Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64'`

If I open the Output tab it shows the following

```
Restoring packages for D:\Project\Windows 10 Developement\Template\HamburgerMenu\HamburgerMenu\project.json...
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform/index.json 938ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform/5.3.3/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform.5.3.3.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform/5.3.3/microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform.5.3.3.nupkg 936ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.compiler/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.compiler/index.json 946ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.compiler/1.6.2/microsoft.net.native.compiler.1.6.2.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.compiler/1.6.2/microsoft.net.native.compiler.1.6.2.nupkg 938ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm/index.json 481ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm.1.6.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/index.json 967ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86/index.json 1438ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86.1.6.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm.1.6.1.nupkg 1347ms
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86.1.6.1.nupkg 1161ms
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg'.
The HTTP request to 'GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64.1.6.1.nupkg' has timed out after 100000ms.
Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64'.
Time Elapsed: 00:27:03.1499426
========== Finished ==========
```

Solution Tried

1. Running as Admin
2. [Nuget error install package Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749164/nuget-error-install-package-microsoft-netcore-universalwindowsplatform)
3. Using `Package Manager Console` to update

**Update**

I have Installed Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64 manually. Now also it is not working.

```
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x86.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86.1.6.1.nupkg'.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Failed to download package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-arm.1.6.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm/1.6.1/microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-arm.1.6.1.nupkg'.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Comment: Really strange issue, in my case, I had to change my default network dns from 8.8.8.8 (google) to 208.67.222.222

Comment: @rubStackOverflow How!!!. I followed the answer below, It works but it caused another problem. [The “ParseILMergeInfoTask” task failed unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088047/the-parseilmergeinfotask-task-failed-unexpectedly)

Comment: Try to change your internet adapter dns to `208.67.222.222`, restart your pc and try again.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow I stay in a hotel, so changing my internet adapter DNS is not possible. I will try it using my mobile data.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow It works. I used my mobile data to download it. So I believe it is a problem due to the internet connection.

Comment: Nice @vijay-nirmal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange issue, in my case, I had to change my default network `DNS`(network card) from 8.8.8.8 to 208.67.222.222.

After that I was able to update `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`.

Answer (score 2):

> Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64'

It is hard to make sure that whether this issue is related to the internet connection, the project itself or others according to the error log, but I could provide you a workaround for this issue:

**Workaround**:

- Download the package "Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64" from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64/).

[image]

- Use nuget [add command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#add) add that package to the global package folder`C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages`:

  `nuget add packagePath -Source sourcePath`

[image]

After that, you will notice the package will be added in to that folder:

[image]
 - Update `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package.

Comment: Can you please expand the second point? What `[options]` to be used? Can you provide a sample add command line?

Comment: That is just an option. It can be omitted if you have no special requirements. For more info, you can refer to the link of add command line in the answer, and I also have update the answer with my test command. Notice that you should switch the path to the directory where nuget.exe exists, for me, it is D:\

Comment: @VijayNirmal, I have noticed that the failed download package are 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x86.1.6.1' and 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-arm.1.6.1' rather than "Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64" in the error log, so the previous error has been resolved, now you can try to install those two packages manually by the same way.

Comment: I will try it and let you know. Also is there is any reason for 'failed download package' error?

Comment: According to the error log, this issue issue seems caused by the network access the nuget.org. You can check whether used any proxy in the Visual Studio, like proxy on fiddler, etc.

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: Now I am having a different problem because of this method. Can you help me? [The “ParseILMergeInfoTask” task failed unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088047/the-parseilmergeinfotask-task-failed-unexpectedly)

Comment: I had this problem for several different packages. I used both the approach listed above: nuget add "C:\Utilities\microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x86.1.7.0.nupkg" -Source "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages" and this on the command line of the Package Manager Console:  Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler -Version 2.1.8

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this problem when trying to run a UWP (Universal Windows Platform) project, and the solution was to select "Developer mode" in the Windows 10 Settings "For Developers"