# The "ParseILMergeInfoTask" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

The program is executing properly without any error in `Debug` configuration But in `Release` configuration it throws an error.

```
The "ParseILMergeInfoTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: File 'SharedAssemblyILMergeInfoFilePath' passed to argument 'x86\ret\SharedAssemblyILMergeInfo.csv' does not exist.
  at Microsoft.Build.ILTasks.ParseILMergeInfoTask.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
  at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I can't run any program in `Release` configuration. It throws the same error.

**Update**

I think I found the problem but I don't know to resolve it. Previously I had an error `Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64'`. To resolve it I follow it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44038629/7331395). So I installed `Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64.1.6.1`, `Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x86.1.6.1` and `Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-arm.1.6.1` manually. Now If I open `Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary-x64` package folder I can't find `build` and `tools` folder within it.[image]

Comment: Since you have resolved your issue, you may reply it as answer  and accepted for sharing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer. Avoid to reply it in the question, thanks for understanding.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I have found the problem but I don't know to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem due to the Internet connection.

1. Just delete the package
   `C:\Users\ponvi\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.sharedlibrary-x64`
2. Download the package using Mobile Data.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158094/7331395) by rubStackOverflow

> Really strange issue, in my case, I had to change my default network
>   DNS(network card) from 8.8.8.8 to 208.67.222.222.